# Override Meteor's exception handling

Tags: javascript, meteor, sentry

I am trying to use sentry.io with Meteor. However Meteor seems to swallow all the errors so even if an exception is thrown manually it won't get picked up by this code.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  console.log('exception')
  console.log(err)
});
```

Is there any way I can add a global error handler to Meteor instead of it's own internal one so I can link it up to custom error handling code?

Answer (score 0):

You always have a chance to catch errors in Meteor (e.g. in a Meteor method) and handle it yourself. E.g.:

```
Meteor.methods({
  someMethod() {
    try {
      const result = callToSentryFunc();

      return result;
    } catch (e) {
      // e === an error object generated by sentry
      throw new Meteor.Error('your-own-error-code',
        'You can throw your own error that gets sent back to the client');
    }
  },
});
```